# C# KeyDown event does not trigger on the form rather the event occurs on some control that is in the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here is a better explanation of the title:

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.Show();
Button b = new Button();
form.Controls.Add(b);
form.KeyDown += (s, args) => MessageBox.Show(args.KeyCode.ToString() + "From form"); // Does not show
b.KeyDown += (s, args) => MessageBox.Show(args.KeyCode.ToString() + " Does show"); // Does show
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Also please let us know what buttons it does work on, and where it doesn't work.

Comment: Share Keydown Event Code.

Comment: your question is confusing. It depends on the focus which control is firing the KeyDown event. Are you asking how to allow only the `Form.KeyDown` event?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a very good problem description. At least tell us what exactly it is you try to achieve, what you have tried and what the ACTUAL problem is.

Comment: Use `KeyPreview = true;` ( helps 99% of the time this question is asked here on SO )

Comment: @waka TY it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

> Form.KeyPreview Property
>
> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx